# Import doesn't work in a similar class

Tags: java, eclipse, import, constructor, undefined

So I have a project in the Eclipse,
with 2 classes, both of them contain an import of another library called Bucket.
Everything works perfectly, but in the third class I created, the import doesn't seem to work and when I create new objects it says the constructor is undefined, while the code is similar among those 3 classes.

I'm sure it's a silly Eclipse problem,
what can cause this?
Thanks

*Edit - Here is the code:*

**This class works fine:**

```
import java.util.*;
import unit4.bucketLib.Bucket;

public class Buck2
{
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        int n, i;
        System.out.println("Type a number of buckets to create");
        n = reader.nextInt();

        Bucket[] bucks = new Bucket[n];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            bucks[i] = new Bucket(20, "Bucket" + (i+1));
```

**This class has errors:**

```
import java.util.*;
import unit4.bucketLib.Bucket;
public class Buck3
{
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        int n, i;
        System.out.println("Type a number of buckets to create");
        n = reader.nextInt();

        Bucket[] bucks = new Bucket[n];

        double rdmcap, rdmfill;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            rdmcap = (Math.random() * 10);
            bucks[i] = new Bucket(rdmcap, "Bucket" + (i+1));
            rdmfill = (Math.random() * rdmcap);
            bucks[i].fill(rdmfill);
        }
```

Comment: Clean the project via project -> clean. See what compilation errors you get now.

Comment: I bet you're doing something wrong.

Comment: By 'similar' can you post how you create the object in each file, and what the imports are?

Comment: Cleaning the project didn't change anything, and about the constructor parameters, it receives a double and a string.

Comment: @amiregelz But I don't think the class has a ctor that takes a double and a String. An integer and a String yes.

Comment: It doesn't work with an int either. I think it's something in the eclipse because even when I create a new class and just copy the whole previous class to it, it should work but it doesn't. I can make a new project and it'll probably work then.

Comment: Nevermind, all I needed to do is close all open blocks. /facepalm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should show the code that has the problem, but I can hazard a guess:

Are you sure the import doesn't work? Most of the time if it says the constructor is undefined it DID find the class you refer to (otherwise you'd get the error that the class isn't found)

Your call to the constructor probably doesn't have the right parameters: if it expects an Integer, and you provide a String, it cannot find the constructor that asks for a String. Check your constructor-calls!

Comment: The problem was way more silly than what I thought. Eclipse doesn't recognize the objects when you create them until you close all open blocks. Thanks anyway.

Comment: And the constructor did in fact ask for a int instead of a double. I was sure it asked for a double because when I put my pointer on the error it said "The constructor Bucket(double, String)", and so I thought that's what it asked for. But it only shows what I sent him.